# How to cancel a pull into branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, pull

I have a problem in with my xcode project. I'm use Sourcetree to manage my projects. I have a branch of my project, and I want update my branch with another updates in the main branch project, so I select the main branch and I did select "pull oringin/mainBranch into my branch".

When I did this, I get conflicts, but while I was resolving this, was committed, and the project.pbxproj was rewrited and now I can't open my project. I get the xcode error:

> Project ... .xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file
>   cannot be parsed.

I'm trying reset to another commit, but when I select the commit that was working, the pull files of the main branch appear in this branch and this have the errors.

I'm in troubles, hope your help

Comment: Did you reset with the option `--hard` or `--mixed` or `--soft`? In this case a hard reset is the best if the target commit is the one you were on before the pull.

Comment: With the option hard, but in pull icon still appear the files of pull

Comment: In the terminal run `git reflog` to find the commit you were on before the pull and make a hard reset to it.

Comment: It show HEAD@{10} and another head, how can select this head to reset to it?

Comment: in the terminal `git reset <commit-id> --hard`

Comment: @ElpieKay thank for your help, but my problem persist, because when I write in the terminal "git reset <commit-id> --hard" this is reset, but the github notification "New changes to commit" 1 ahead 3 behind is showed again. And this was the HEAD of checkout moving from branches before I did the pull. How can solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151148/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-user3745888).

Answer (score 0):

create a new clone local and compare this with the folder and files that fail. For example with winmerge or notepad++ compare files. This tell you what's wrong and what is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is actually `git fetch` + `git merge` of the remote branch into your local branch.

The first parent of this merge commit is your previous HEAD, so you have to do

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

After this, your local branch is pointing to the commit prior to `git pull`.

This supposes your last commit is actually the merge commit. If it doesn't, you have to determine which it is (and substitute HEAD by the hash of this commit).